# Why am I getting "The name Regex does not exist in the current context" from my C# code?

Tags: c#, regex

Why am I getting this error:

> The name Regex does not exist in the current context.

from my code?

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(string1, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
```

Comment: Add an import to the top of your cs file?..

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to your project and a using directive to the code? (`using System.Text.RegularExpressions`)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make sure you have the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace referenced.

Answer (score 11):

You need to include the right namespace to access the `Regex` class:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to the top of your class file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have included the 'using' and still no luck, instantiate it first.

```
string regexPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+$";    
Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(string1);
if(m.Success)
{
   // Win!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Regex` class doesn't exist in your program. However, if you reference it from some outside library, you will be able to use it in your program.

To be able to use the `Regex` class and all its features, add the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you typed `Regex.IsMatch` and not `RegEx.IsMatch` with a capital E.  I've gotten this wrong before.